# loop through hex/prop_id values

Tags: c++, hex

I am writing a program in c++ for pst extractions.

I want to check all the possible prop_ids and the best way i can think of for this is to loop through them. in c++ i can declare a `prop_id` by just calling

```
prop_id = 0x0000
```

I want to increase the 0000 side of this. This `prop_id` expects a hexadecimal number. How can i increase the value of 0000. I have tried just

```
prop_id pid = 0x000;
```

followed with pid++ but this seems to return a hex 8 places long.

Comment: Sounds to me like you have 32-bit integers and you are expecting them to behave as 16-bit.  That's not necessarily a problem, but your explanation is unclear.  Show exactly what you expect when you increment, and how you are determining the 'length' of the number.  I mean, are you printing it to screen/file?  Are you looking at memory contents?

Comment: when i increment i expect 0x0000 (min) .. 0x00A3 .. 0xFFFF (max). With this data i will be trying to access mapi pst properties. I can just use 0x3456 for example but i want to see if i am missing mapi properties by just looping though all possible hex values.

Comment: the above is a small example of the increment i expect. 0x0001 0x0002 and so on

Answer (score 2):

I still don't understand the question.  Perhaps because you are confused about what a hex number is.  Inside the computer, the bits are just the same whether we write the number in base 2 (binary), 8 (octal), 10 (decimal), or 16 (hexadecimal).

So, take the number 16...  These are all the same:

```
unsigned short pid = 0b10000;  // binary (prefix with '0b' -- GCC only)
unsigned short pid = 020;      // octal (prefix with '0')
unsigned short pid = 16;       // decimal (no prefix)
unsigned short pid = 0x10;     // hexadecimal (prefix with '0x')
```

To loop through, just go:

```
for( int i = 0; i <= 0xffff; i++ ) {
    printf( "%04x = %d\n", i, i );
}
```

If you use `unsigned short` (a 16-bit integer), you need to be careful when you loop.  If you looped an `unsigned short` with the construction above it would loop forever, because after incrementing `0xffff` it would wrap back to zero.  You can do this instead:

```
unsigned short i = 0;
do {
    printf( "%04hx = %hu\n", i, i );
    i++;
} while( i != 0 );  // Will become zero after completing 0xffff iteration.
```

Anyway, the point is that if you are just sending numbers to some function, it doesn't matter whether you play with them as hex, decimal or whatever...  They're all the same.  If you need to output it, see my `printf` calls.